# How to show PayPal BNPL popup in shopify using custom code?

Tags: paypal, shopify, liquid

I changed my bnpl design using custom code, but I can't find how to show the pop up for PayPal. The other buttons are showing a popup but I can't in PayPal

[image]

[image]

All the other buttons are working.

here is my code for product page

```
{% render 'interest-logo' %}
```

here is my code in theme.liquid

```
<script>
let invertvalId = null;

let workid = function(err){
  let afterpayText = document.querySelector('afterpay-placement').shadowRoot.children[1].children[0].innerText;
  if(afterpayText){
    document.querySelector('.after_pay-text').innerText = afterpayText; 
    document.querySelector('#afterPlay').addEventListener('click', function(e){
     document.querySelector('afterpay-placement').shadow.querySelector('button').click();
    }); 
    document.querySelector('#paypal_bnpl').addEventListener('click', function(e){
      //Paypal popup
    });
    document.querySelector('#latitude_pay').addEventListener('click', function(e){
      document.querySelector('.lp-pdp-container img').click();
    });
    document.querySelector('#zip_payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
      document.querySelector('quadpay-widget').shadowRoot.querySelector('#qp-logo-last').click();
    });
    
    clearInterval(invertvalId);
  }else{
    console.log('Null')
  }
}
  invertvalId = setInterval(workid, 100);


document.querySelector('.product-form').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(document.querySelector('afterpay-placement').shadowRoot.children[1].children[0].innerText);
})
```

here is my code in interest-logo.liquid

```
    <div class="after_pay-text"></div>
<div class="interest_logo">
<span class="afterpay-logo-link" id="afterPlay">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="98" height="36" class="compact-badge-logo" viewBox="0 0 100 21">
    <path class="afterpay-logo-badge-background" fill="#b2fce4" d="M89.85 20.92h-78.9a10.42 10.42 0 110-20.82h78.89a10.42 10.42 0 010 20.83v-.01z"></path>
    <g class="afterpay-logo-badge-lockup">
      <path d="M85.05 6.37L82.88 5.1l-2.2-1.27a2.2 2.2 0 00-3.3 1.9v.29c0 .16.08.3.22.38l1.03.58c.28.16.63-.04.63-.37v-.67c0-.34.36-.54.65-.38l2.02 1.16 2 1.15c.3.16.3.58 0 .75l-2 1.15-2.02 1.16a.43.43 0 01-.65-.38v-.33a2.2 2.2 0 00-3.28-1.9l-2.2 1.26-2.19 1.25a2.2 2.2 0 000 3.8l2.18 1.25 2.2 1.27a2.2 2.2 0 003.3-1.9v-.3c0-.15-.09-.3-.23-.37L78.02 14a.43.43 0 00-.64.37v.67c0 .34-.36.54-.65.38l-2-1.16-2-1.15a.43.43 0 010-.75l2-1.15 2-1.16c.3-.16.65.05.65.38v.33a2.2 2.2 0 003.3 1.9l2.2-1.26 2.17-1.25a2.2 2.2 0 000-3.8z"></path>
      <path d="M70.77 6.78l-5.1 10.53h-2.12l1.91-3.93-3-6.6h2.17l1.93 4.42 2.1-4.42h2.11z"></path>
      <path d="M19.8 10.5c0-1.24-.92-2.12-2.04-2.12s-2.03.9-2.03 2.14c0 1.23.91 2.14 2.03 2.14s2.03-.88 2.03-2.14m.02 3.74v-.97a3 3 0 01-2.36 1.09c-2.05 0-3.6-1.65-3.6-3.86 0-2.2 1.61-3.87 3.65-3.87.95 0 1.76.42 2.31 1.08v-.95h1.84v7.48h-1.84z"></path>
      <path d="M30.6 12.6c-.65 0-.84-.24-.84-.87V8.4h1.2V6.78h-1.2V4.96h-1.88v1.82h-2.43v-.74c0-.63.24-.87.9-.87h.42V3.72h-.9c-1.56 0-2.3.5-2.3 2.07v1h-1.04V8.4h1.04v5.85h1.88V8.4h2.43v3.66c0 1.53.6 2.19 2.11 2.19h.97V12.6h-.37z"></path>
      <path d="M37.35 9.85c-.13-.97-.93-1.56-1.86-1.56-.92 0-1.7.57-1.88 1.56h3.74zM33.6 11c.13 1.1.93 1.74 1.93 1.74.8 0 1.4-.37 1.76-.97h1.94c-.45 1.58-1.87 2.6-3.74 2.6a3.68 3.68 0 01-3.85-3.85 3.78 3.78 0 013.9-3.9 3.74 3.74 0 013.8 4.38H33.6z"></path>
      <path d="M51.35 10.5c0-1.2-.9-2.12-2.03-2.12-1.12 0-2.03.9-2.03 2.14 0 1.23.9 2.14 2.03 2.14 1.12 0 2.03-.93 2.03-2.14m-5.92 6.79V6.78h1.84v.97a2.97 2.97 0 012.36-1.1c2.02 0 3.6 1.65 3.6 3.85s-1.6 3.87-3.65 3.87a2.9 2.9 0 01-2.26-1v3.93h-1.9.01z"></path>
      <path d="M59.86 10.5c0-1.24-.9-2.12-2.03-2.12-1.12 0-2.04.9-2.04 2.14 0 1.23.92 2.14 2.04 2.14s2.03-.88 2.03-2.14m.02 3.74v-.97a3 3 0 01-2.36 1.09c-2.05 0-3.6-1.65-3.6-3.86 0-2.2 1.61-3.87 3.64-3.87.96 0 1.76.42 2.32 1.08v-.95h1.84v7.48h-1.84z"></path>
      <path d="M42.11 7.5s.47-.86 1.62-.86c.5 0 .8.17.8.17v1.9s-.69-.42-1.32-.33c-.64.09-1.04.67-1.04 1.45v4.42h-1.9V6.78h1.84v.73z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</span>


<div id="paypal_bnpl" class="message__logo-container" aria-label="PayPal Credit"><div class="message__logo message__logo--svg"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" role="presentation" alt="PayPal Credit" aria-hidden="true"></div><div class="message__logo message__logo--svg"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" role="presentation" alt="PayPal Credit" aria-hidden="true"></div></div>

<div class="latitude_pay" id="latitude_pay">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0622/1863/3451/files/LatitudePay_Logo_Horiz_Blue_RGB.png?v=1665109566">
</div>
<div id="zip_payment">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0622/1863/3451/files/Zip_Logo-768x281-_1.png?v=1665108735">
</div>
</div>

<style>
.after_pay-text {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
  div[data-pp-message] {
    display: none !important;
}
  .qp-widget-container, afterpay-placement {
    display: none;
}
 
  .interest_logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  .interest_logo img{
    height: 18px;
}
  .message__logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
  div#klarna {
    margin-right: 8px;
    display: none!important;
}
  div#latitude_pay {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance! :)